# How to query xml column in tsql

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery

I have a table, T1, with a XML column, EventXML, on SQL Server 2008. I want to query all the rows where certain node contains a particular value. Better, I'd like to retrieve the value in a different node. The table T1:

```
T1:
   EventID, int
   EventTime, datetime
   EventXML, XML
```

Here is an example XML hierarchy:

```
<Event>
   <Indicator>
      <Name>GDP</Name>
   </Indicator>
   <Announcement>
      <Value>2.0</Value>
      <Date>2012-01-01</Date>
   </Announcement>
</Event>
```

1. How to find all the rows related to "GDP" Indicator;
2. How to get all values for "GDP" Indicator;

Answer (score 65, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT 
    EventID, EventTime,
    AnnouncementValue = t1.EventXML.value('(/Event/Announcement/Value)[1]', 'decimal(10,2)'),
    AnnouncementDate = t1.EventXML.value('(/Event/Announcement/Date)[1]', 'date')
FROM
    dbo.T1
WHERE
    t1.EventXML.exist('/Event/Indicator/Name[text() = "GDP"]') = 1
```

It will find all rows where the `/Event/Indicator/Name` equals `GDP` and then it will display the `<Announcement>/<Value>` and `<Announcement>/<Date>` for those rows.

See [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaf6f/1)

Comment: because every other solution used the declare statement and i was confused how to do it inline.

Answer (score 9):

```
DECLARE @t XML = '
<Event>
   <Indicator>
      <Name>GDP</Name>
   </Indicator>
   <Announcement>
      <Value>2.0</Value>
      <Date>2012-01-01</Date>
   </Announcement>
</Event>
<Event>
   <Indicator>
      <Name>Other</Name>
   </Indicator>
   <Announcement>
      <Value>3.0</Value>
      <Date>2012-01-01</Date>
   </Announcement>
</Event>
'

SELECT  node.value('.', 'NUMERIC(20, 2)')
FROM    @t.nodes('/Event[Indicator/Name/node()=''GDP'']/Announcement/Value') t(node)
```