# how to select specific value from text column containing an xml string?

Tags: sql, xml, regex, string, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using sql server 2008 r2, I have `my_table` containing `my_col` of type `text` which contains `xml`, I want to select an attribute from the root element of that xml and convert it to a `bit` type (the attribute takes the value 'true'/'false') when I select a particular row from the table, rather than selecting out the whole string and passing it back to the server as its quite a long string and I could be selecting many rows at a time. I'm not too good with regex or sql. Here is the format of my text/xml column:

```
<rootElementName <!--lots of attributes--> Recommended="false"><!--...lots of stuff in here...--></rootElementName>
```

I just want to select out `0` for rows that have `Recommended="false"` and `1` for `Recommended="true"`.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: And if that column contains XML - then why isn't it of datatype `XML` ?!?!?

Comment: because it was originally implemented by some one who had absolutely no idea what they were doing now I have to live with it like that, I will ask the team if the table schema can be updated to change that column to xml type, but Im guessing there will be some flakey reason it can't be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to convert your text column to an xml type and then do the XQuery.

```
SELECT convert(XML,my_col).value('(/rootElementName/@Recommended)[1]', 'bit') rec
FROM  my_table
```

I looked up/adapted stuff from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195922/how-to-query-xml-column-in-tsql) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846990/extracting-attributes-from-xml-fields-in-sql-server-2008-table) question.

The conversion idea came from [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/converting-string-data-to-xml-and-xml-to-string-data/)

Here is a working **[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e7d3/1/0)**